# How to filter some database records with Join in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm working with Join in laravel, I'm getting result in one part, but now I need to pick up only some records that are active but I can not implement. My query would be this:

```
$queryBuilder = $query->parse(
    $queryBuilderJSON, DB::table('tab_person')
    ->where('deleted_at', NULL)
    ->leftJoin('tab_user', 'tab_person.pac_r', '=', 'tab_user.reg_id'));
   // 'tab_user.reg_status', '=', 'A' **I can not implement this condition, how can I do it?**
```

Ignore queryBuilderJSON, I'm working with it to use Query Builder Jquery, which is a search library. What I just need to know is how to filter the USER records that are only active (they are represented by the letter 'A') and the line is commented out in the code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple join conditions using a closure:

```
->leftJoin('tab_user', function ($query) {
    $query->on('tab_person.pac_r', '=', 'tab_user.reg_id');
    $query->where('tab_user.reg_status', '=', 'A');
});
```

You can learn more on advanced join clauses in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins).

Comment: Hey guy, thanks! just change the second option because it does not work. The resulting data is only the quantity of the second table.